# Shouldn't every class that inherits an interface implement all interface members?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

What is the difference between `ClassTemp1` and `ClassTemp2<T>`?

I thought every class that implements an interface should implement all the interface members but `ClassTemp2<T>` has no error. Why?

```
public interface ITemp : IComparable
{
    void Temp();
}

public class ClassTemp1 : ITemp // Error
{

}

public class ClassTemp2<T> where T : ITemp // No Error
{

}
```

Comment: `T` has to implement it, not `ClassTemp2`

Comment: `ClassTemp2` doesn't inherit from `ITemp`, `where` defines the constraints where `T` should comply

Comment: Aha,,,! Thanks Adrian !

Comment: Thanks mshwf. I understand.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your English wasn't bad at all - it was easy to understand what you meant. I've tried to edit it to make it more easily readable - hopefully it still reflects your intent, feel free to roll it back if I've made any mistakes.

Comment: Thank you DaveyDaveDave. It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The class `ClassTemp2` is not inheriting or implementing any interface. Just your "parameter class" `T` implements it.

In other words: `ClassTemp2` may do something with `T` and it's methods, in particular, calling the `Temp()` method of `T` in it's own methods.

`ClassTemp2` does not "have" or "implements" the `ITemp` interface. Just, the "parameter class" `T` does, not `ClassTemp2`.

I hope, this help.